# Obsidian covers only part of the screen in Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a Linux newbie and am slowly transitioning into Linux from Windows 11 using WSL2. I use Obsidian quite a bit in my workflow and recently installed Obsidian in my Ubuntu distro (22.04.2). While Obsidian works fine othervise, it renders weiredly when I maximize the Obsidian window. The maximized screen only covers part of the screen leaving thin strips  of the desktop to the left and to the top empty. The buttons to restore and close the window also moves out of the screen to the right and it becomes pretty difficult to restore or close the window once I maximise it.

I have tried both the AppImage and the deb installation, but the problem persists. This does not happen with any other software that I am using on Ubuntu.

Can someone please help me figure this one out?

Thanks in advance!

[screenshot of my maximized obsidian window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl3HK.png)

Comment: What does your `wsl --version` show?  If it only outputs help text, then that's useful information as well.  Thanks!